# Meaning of "work better for silence"

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions

Holmes and Watson are alone in the room.

> Holmes: I shall **work better for silence**.
>
> Watson: Oh, well. I dare say I can find something quiet to do.

Does he mean he needs silence to work? And why does he use *for*? Isn't it right to say *in silence*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he's saying he would work better if it were quiet.  Nowadays I think you'd see "in silence".   The example is a more archaic usage, but I believe it falls under [this definition](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=archaic%20use%20of%20%27for%27#hl=en&q=for&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=uoTdT6uKFqf66QGe8ryxCw&ved=0CF4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=cb0e8e16451f2e65&biw=1066&bih=562) of "for":

> Having (the thing mentioned) as a reason or cause ... *I could dance and sing for joy*

Comment: Surely *in silence* would mean Holmes saying nothing while Watson prattled: not what I understand by the quotation.

Comment: @TimLymington:  I would interpret "I work better in silence" to mean "I work better *when it's quiet*" but I can see your interpretation as equally valid.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it means that Holmes wants to work in silence. *For* is used  here with the sense 'if there is'. *For* has many uses, of which this is just one.

Answer (score 1):

*In silence* would mean 'without talking'; a teacher might instruct pupils to *work in silence*.  Holmes means that he wants to work without anyone else talking.  *For* here means 'in the condition'; *I work better for knowing I am appreciated*.